# How do I identify the source of Cosmos DB RU consumption?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

**Context**

I have an Azure Function which executes daily, it is change tracking a pricing feed with the results stored in a Cosmos DB.  Each time it runs it compares the latest price from the feed, against the most recent values in the DB collection and writes a new item if there is a difference.  It is scheduled to run at 23:55 each day.  The overall setup is tiny, with 10 items in the DB, and changes seen usually once a week.  My consumption is 3.84 RUs for the daily execution when the price hasn't changed.

**Question**

In addition to the expected activity at 23:55 each day, there is additional activity appearing almost every 3 hrs 45 mins.  This unexpected activity consumes 4 RUs each time (around 24 RUs per day).  How can I identify the source of the additional activity?

**Other info**

I noticed that the backups were scheduled to 4 hours, so I changed that to daily.  That didn't help.

Since noticing the additional usage I have added diagnostic settings to save all logs into a Log Analytics workspace.  I can see that the RUs are Read operations, Type = AzureDiagnostics, requestResourceType = Collection, Source IP = 51.11.40.180, 1 of the 4 is a read against the __Cosmos/colls/__Query collection.  This suggests to me that it's the diagnostics causing the cost.  I disabled the diagnostic settings to see if that reduced my RU consumption, but it does not.

Is it just a case that diagnostics are run by Microsoft and that is simply part of having a cosmos db?
And that usually it's a smaller proportion of the overall cost, therefore not an issue?

Comment: You can look at the Azure logs, as a starting point. That said: You pay for RU/second (with the lowest amount being 400 RU/sec for a collection or shared-RU database). You don't pay per query. And 4 RU is like... background noise. Especially if you're talking about one single query.

Comment: Queries against the master partition is the likely culprit. These can be anything from opening the portal to view your Cosmos account to other operations or when you create a new instance of the SDK client and get a reference to your databases and containers. That said, 24 RU/s over a day is an extremely small amount of throughput to be concerned with since minimum 400 RU per second. In fact this workload is ideal for serverless throughput. I would take a look at that. Most likely is cheaper than standard throughput.